# Connect to remote server using python, adding proxy

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to execute a command on a remote server. When I try to connect to it with the help of  `paramiko`, it fails while giving the `ProxyCommand`

```
client.connect(
    host['hostname'], username=host['user'],
    password='xxxx@***',
    sock=paramiko.ProxyCommand(host.get('ProxyCommand ssh <proxy_server_address>:1234 nc %h %p'))
)
```

What is the correct approach to pass the `ProxyCommand`, for establishing the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need to give the word `ProxyCommand`, try this:

```
sock = paramiko.ProxyCommand("ssh {}@{} nc <proxy_server_address>:1234".format(host_cfg.get('username'), host_cfg.get('host')))
```